# Google maps having an issue with another iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the latest Google Maps Api and it works fine until I try to embed an iframe from another source to the page.

I'm not using an iframe to call the google map api, I'm using a div tag that's named. The iframe has nothing to do with Google maps. However, the page works fine if I don't add an iframe but doesn't when I do.

I was wondering why on earth would adding an iframe to a page cause the google maps api to fail?

Comment: Without seeing any code it is really hard to say. Chances are there is a bug/typo somewhere in your javascript/html. Can you post some code or a link to an example?

Comment: Also, what does Firebug, etc, say? Any errors listed in the console?

Comment: Good point that I should test with firebug. I was just amazed that adding an iframe to the page would upset the Google maps api that's already working fine. As for an example of the template I'm using you can look at http://www.sanfernandovalleyokay.com/3EW0BG9DH-3EW0BG9DL.htm

Comment: OK, that page seems to be working, and there is no iframe defined. Can you post an example with an IFrame that isn't working...without seeing the code that is causing the error is impossible to help.

Comment: Well, I might be able to do that tomorrow. We're regenerating all our pages for all our sites and so I can't interrupt our test server from building the pages just yet. What I'll do tomorrow is add the iframe in question to the local version on the test server and just allow access through our firewall so you can take a look.

Comment: I think I may have just stumbled upon a problem. It could be inside the .css that I'm using in the iframe. It calls the same .css as the main page does that is called inside the iframe. I won't be able to test that until tomorrow tho. I'll let you know.

Comment: Well I was called away for some other stuff. So sorry about seeming like I disappear there for a few days. Anyway I tested the iframe call without any .css inside the page it calls and still no dice.

Comment: Ok, I feel like such a tool. The issue was that I was not ending the frame with </iframe> tag. Sorry to bother you for nothing. LOL :P

Comment: re-read the first comment I made here...and remember for next time ;)

Comment: The first thing I did was check the code, but did not remember that it required an ending tag for an iframe because I forgot that you can put things inside an iframe for when a browser doesn't support frames. What's funny is it's usually the simple mistakes that are the hardest to find because you never think for a second you could make those kinds of simple mistakes. I thought I was loosing my mind for a second that the map on the page wouldn't load up just for adding an iframe. I was certain that was not possible, and apparently I was right, but coded wrong. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Google maps cannot be called from an iframe. Simple